# How to convert Api response into Array Swift 5 (concatenate)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

/email5600@gmail.com_conemp.pdf,@,uploadedFiles/email5600@gmail.com_p3037c.pdf,@,profilepics/mj.tm@hotmail.com.jpeg

How to remove @ between array in Swift

Comment: I think you want to try and split on `,@,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split your string in an array:

```
let str = "/email5600@gmail.com_conemp.pdf,@,uploadedFiles/email5600@gmail.com_p3037c.pdf,@,profilepics/mj.tm@hotmail.com.jpeg"
let result = str.split(separator: ",@,")
```

Comment: i got that array from api response so how i remove ,@,